# How to Highlight a Feature layer within a graphic layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a map service that has 2 layers. One is a polygon layer that contains a combination of polygons, and the other is a point layer that contains many points located both inside and outside of the large polygon in the form of a graphic layer.

How to highlight the polygon layer within the point layer(in graphic form). using ArcGIS server and ArcGIS javascript api,

Answer (score 1):

First define a hightlightening style to the polygons layer, with a selection symbol.

Then select a polygon, using an intersection between Polygons and Points.

```
var selectionSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255,255,0,0.5]));
polygonsLayer.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

var query = new Query();
query.geometry = a_point_geometry;
query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
polygonsLayer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (feature) {
  map.centerAt(feature[0].geometry.getCentroid());
});
```